# Can't install electron with npm, what could be wrong?

Tags: node.js, npm, electron

I am using Mac OSX sierra. I was using on el Capitan then I updated and now it's not working. I tried a clean installation of node and npm, even after that it's not working. I try "npm install electron --save-dev" but it get stuck on node install.js. I left it for an hour still no change.

I tried other packages from npm its working. 
I tried "npm install express" it worked. 
[image]

Comment: Mac OS upgrade significant;y change the underlying C libs. Have you run `brew doctor`? Are you using the latest XCode? Did you reinstall Node after the upgrade (node binds to libs that were probably upgraded)?

Comment: i installed latest command line developer tool and yes i reinstalled node after update ..i even clean install brew after update

Answer (score 4):

I also faced the same issue. It is downloading the files actually.

File size ~45MB so, it takes some time. You can use `--verbose` flag to see the download status details.

```
$ npm install -g electron --verbose
```

Comment: No still stuck at reify:@electron/get: info run electron@25.2.0 postinstall node_modules/electron node install.js

Answer (score 1):

This usually caused by an error of your network.
You computer cannot connect to the source of the files mentioned in **install.js** (not npm respositories), or running at a very low speed.
You may try

`npm install -g cnpm --registry=https://registry.npm.taobao.org`

then

`cnpm install electron`

And probably wait for **several minutes**?

Be patient.

Comment: ⸨      ░░░░░░░░░░░░⸩ ⠙ fetchMetadata: verb cache add spec utility@^1.9.0
stuck here after first command

Comment: Emm..It seems that this is really a network problem.You really should improve your network quality :)

Comment: by quality u mean speed? i have 150 KBps download speed

Comment: tnx for ur help yang...appreciate it

Comment: if you are on a corporate network, github may be throttling connection requests to your company because it sees many requests right now from a single IP address.

Answer (score 0):

electron will download from remote, maybe you can try to use proxy or just use [cnpm](https://github.com/cnpm/cnpm) just as @Claim Yang said or try yarn [yarn](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn), hope that help you.